# How to load key in RSA using phpseclib

Tags: rsa, phpseclib

I am using the phpseclib3 library

```php
use phpseclib3\\Crypt\\PublicKeyLoader;
use phpseclib3\\Crypt\\RSA;

$key = PublicKeyLoader::loadPrivateKey($private_key, $private_key_password);
return RSA::createKey()->loadPrivateKey($key, $private_key_password)->withHash('sha256')->withMGFHash('sha256')->withSaltLength(32)->sign($signing_string);
```

It is showing

```
error : load() should not be called from final classes (phpseclib3\\Crypt\\RSA\\PrivateKey)
```

I want to pass my Key to RSA to generate signing string.

Comment: Which line is causing the error?

Comment: Your code makes no sense. You load the private key (`$key`) in the penultimate line. Then you create a new private key with `createKey()` in the last line and then try to load `$key` again (the latter results in the error message). To fix the issue you only need to replace `RSA::createKey()->loadPrivateKey($key, $private_key_password)` with `$key`, s. https://phpsandbox.io/e/x/2b7t2#index.php.

Comment: If you're _loading_ a private key you can do so simply by doing `PublicKeyLoader::load($private_key, $private_key_password)`. If you're _creating_ an RSA private key from scratch then you don't need to load it at all - `RSA::createKey()` _returns_ a private key.